# sort function in python for loop doesn't repeat

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
n = int(input())
string = input()
string_list = list(string)

division_list = []
for i in range(n):
    if n%(i+1) == 0:
        division_list.append(i+1)
division_list.sort(reverse=True)
print(division_list)

for division in division_list:
    temp1 = string_list[:division]
    temp2 = string_list[division:]
    print('before reverse')
    print(temp1)
    temp1.sort(reverse=True)
    print('after reverse')
    print(temp1)
    string_list = temp1 + temp2

ans = ''.join(string_list)
print(ans)
```

I was solving problem in code forces, and realized sort function doesn't work more than one in for loop. Why? And is there any further stuffs I can do on my code?
This is the link of the question.
https://codeforces.com/problemset/problem/999/B

edited)
I put 4 and abcd as a input. This is the output. I expected to see ['c', 'd'] after second temp1.sort(reverse=True). But it doesn't reversed.

```
4
abcd
[4, 2, 1]
before reverse
['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']
after reverse
['d', 'c', 'b', 'a']
before reverse
['d', 'c']
after reverse
['d', 'c']
before reverse
['d']
after reverse
['d']
dcba
```

Comment: What do you mean by "sort function doesn't work more than one in for loop"? Can you show the specific problem you're having?

Comment: Can you give an example of input where you get output you don't expect? And describe what you expect and what you get instead?

Comment: @dspencer If you run this code, you'll see temp1.sort(reverse=True) function won't work from second for loop.
I do test with
4 for 1st input
abcd for 2nd input

Comment: Make it easy for us, we shouldn't _have_ to run the code to see your problem - please indicate in the question exactly what isn't working as you expect.

Comment: sorry for inconvenience! I edited my question.

Comment: In all the cases after the first, the list happened to already be in reverse order - there wasn't anything for `.sort()` to do.  If you wanted to reverse whatever order the list happened to have, that's not a job for `.sort()`, that's `temp1 = temp1[::-1]`.

Comment: Omg I was so stupid. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Python .sort function sorts the list in ascending order.  What the reverse parameter does is reverses the sorted list; so in this case in descending order, which happens to be the original list.

If you are trying to reverse the list I think `temp1.reverse()` would work (https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-list-reverse/). Otherwise, you could do something like this:

`temp1 = temp1[::-1]`